# Date format in a textfield

Tags: date, format, sencha-touch-2, textfield

I have a textfield:

```
xtype: "fieldset",
items:[
   {
    xtype: "textfield",
    name: "dateScanned",
    label: "Datum",
    disabled: true,
    tpl: "{dateScanned:date('d/m/Y H:i')}"  // <--- this dosn't work
   }
]
```

My Store is:

```
fields: [
    { name: 'dateScanned', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'c' }
]
```

Why does the marked point not work?
How can I realize that the date is fomatted?

Comment: Are you sure the data coming in is in 'c' format? Do you get anything when you leave off the format in your template?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. But I have the solution. See next post. Better late than never.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution:

dateFormat instead of tpl

```
xtype: "fieldset",
items:[
   {
    xtype: "datepickerfield",
    name: "dateScanned",
    label: "Datum",
    disabled: true,
    dateFormat: "d.m.Y H:i"
    //tpl: "{dateScanned:date('d/m/Y H:i')}"  // <--- this dosn't work
   }
]
```

I  don't know, but I believe to remember that it is important to set the double question marks.

Comment: This simply does not work. dateFormat is not a property of textfield in Sencha Touch 2.

Comment: Oh, I make a mistake. I used the xtype "datepickerfield" instead of "textfield" and set disabled to true. I correct my answer now. Your answer below may work, too. I can't check this today. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

```
/*Override to allow textfields to format dates*/
Ext.override(Ext.field.Text, {
    setValue: function (value) {
        if (this.config.dateFormat && value) {
            if (Ext.isDate(value)) {
                value = Ext.Date.format(value, this.config.dateFormat);
            }
            else {
                var d = new Date(value);
                value = Ext.Date.format(d, this.config.dateFormat);
            }
        }
        this.callSuper(arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

MyAppWhere do you insert that override up there? 
If i add a new Text.js under app/field/Text.js and link it under require it doesn't work

**SOLUTION**

```
/*Override to allow textfields to format dates*/
Ext.define('MyApp.field.Text', {
override: 'Ext.field.Text', 
    setValue: function (value) {
        if (this.config.dateFormat && value) {
            if (Ext.isDate(value)) {
                value = Ext.Date.format(value, this.config.dateFormat);
            }
            else {
                var d = new Date(value);
                value = Ext.Date.format(d, this.config.dateFormat);
            }
        }
        this.callSuper(arguments);
    }
});
```

You create a folder in your project Project/app/field/Text.js and put the code in
And then under requires add

```
requires: [            
        'MyApp.field.Text'
    ],
```

Comment: this works , but override is now deprecated, so I used extend